# pandas plot x data out of order?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

using ubuntu 18.04.1 lts  python 3.6.7 matplotlib 2.1.1 pandas 0.23.4
 and trying to plot the following test data on a line chart. So it should end up as a line left to right with points at 10 50 100

[image]

```
the x_axes  = hv_20 hv_10 hv_5
the y axes  = 10     50    100
```

the code below SEEMS to be plotting

```
the x_axes = **hv_10 hv_20** hv_5

the y_axes = **50    10**    100
```

I can't figure out why and can't seem to find the documentation which helps me out.

what am I doing wrong please?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def mini_plot( data_frame ):

        fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=20 , ncols=10, sharey=True, figsize=(10,5))

        axes_list = [item for sublist in axes for item in sublist] 

        for index, row in data_frame.iterrows(): 
              ax = axes_list.pop(0)

              y_axes = pd.DataFrame(data_frame.iloc[ index ].values[3:6])

              print("index = ", data_frame.iloc[ index ][3:6].index)

              plt.ylim(0 , 100)

              ax.set_xlabel(row.Symbol ,labelpad= 0 )

              #x_axes = ['20', '10' , '5' ]

              x_axes = data_frame.iloc[ index ][3:6].index

              #ax.set_xticklabels( x_axes )

              ax.plot( x_axes, y_axes ,  label = "min", color= 'g' , linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.5)


        for ax in axes_list:
              ax.remove()

        plt.show()



if __name__  == '__main__' :

        test_data =     [ ('20181126#AAPL' , '2018-11-26',  'AAPL' , 10,  50, 100) ]

        test_labels =  [ 'Id',  'Date' ,  'Symbol' ,   'Hv_20' , 'Hv_10', 'Hv_5' ]

        df_todays_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records( test_data , columns = test_labels)


        mini_plot( df_todays_data )
```

Comment: It plots as expected 10-50-100 in my environment. An older matplotlib version sorted automatically categorical data (`Hv20` etc.). Update your matplotlib and your problem is gone.

Comment: @Mr.T thanks for the reply I'm running matplotlib 2.1.1 which version are you running please?

Comment: @theakson matplotlib is on release 3.0.x right now, I would just update to the newest version if possible.

Comment: @LucasLeodler thk for reply I ran sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib as soon as Mr.T suggested it and the version is the same? I have added a picture as my description sucks

Comment: just tried  pip3 install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.1.1)

Comment: The update would be `pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib`.

Comment: @Mr.T you are a god! It worked straight away. I am a clod for NOT spotting this and apologize unreservedly for what can only be described as abject laziness on my part. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it works now. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Mr.T thanks again but I can't mark this as an answer for some reason.

Comment: [You are allowed to write and accept your own answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mr.t answered my question. I was using and old version of  matplotlib 2.1.1 and the current version IS 3.0.x  I applied the update to my system and BINGO!!

pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib